# Hadoop Datanode runs only once and then does not start again on Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, hadoop, hdfs

I was trying to install Hadoop
and run a simple sample program

Datanode started only for "1" - one time and then I started getting this error

```
2021-01-06 23:48:25,610 INFO checker.ThrottledAsyncChecker: Scheduling a check for [DISK]file:/C:/hadoop/sbin/datanode
2021-01-06 23:48:25,666 WARN checker.StorageLocationChecker: Exception checking StorageLocation [DISK]file:/C:/hadoop/sbin/datanode
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.stat(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/nativeio/NativeIO$POSIX$Stat;
at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.stat(Native Method)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.getStat(NativeIO.java:608)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfoByNativeIO(RawLocalFileSystem.java:823)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:737)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:705)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.mkdirsWithExistsAndPermissionCheck(DiskChecker.java:233)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDirInternal(DiskChecker.java:141)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.StorageLocation.check(StorageLocation.java:239)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.StorageLocation.check(StorageLocation.java:52)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.checker.ThrottledAsyncChecker$1.call(ThrottledAsyncChecker.java:142)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:57)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)              
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-01-06 23:48:25,671 ERROR datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Too many failed volumes - current valid volumes: 0, volumes configured: 1, volumes failed: 1, volume failures tolerated: 0
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.checker.StorageLocationChecker.check(StorageLocationChecker.java:233)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2841)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2754)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2798)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2942)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2966)
2021-01-06 23:48:25,675 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Too many failed volumes - current valid volumes: 0, volumes configured: 1, volumes failed: 1, volume failures tolerated: 0
```

I have referred to many different articles but to no avail. I have tried to use another version of Hadoop but the problem remains and as I am just starting out, I can't fully understand the problem therefore I need help

these are my configurations

```
                -For core-site.xml 

<configuration>
 <property>
 <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
 <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
    
                - For mapred-site.xml 


<configuration>
 <property>
 <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
 <value>yarn</value>
 </property>
</configuration>

                -For yarn-site.xml 

<configuration>
 <property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
 <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.auxservices.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
 </property>
</configuration>



                -For hdfs-site.xml


<configuration>
 <property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
 <value>1</value>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
 <value>C:\hadoop\data\namenode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
 <value>datanode</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

After every successful running of Datanode, a Folder named `"datanode"` gets created in the `sbin` directory
which I have to delete before running Datanode again.

Don't know the logic and reason but seems to work.

Comment: That worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't gracefully stop the datanode and namenode (for example, just shutdown the computer), there's potential for corruption, and will cause it not to start without reformatting

It's also generally not recommended to use Windows filesystem or NTFS formatted drives for running HDFS